# Avoiding ambiguous column errors when using JOIN in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli

My query looks like this:

```
$sql = "
SELECT u.*, s.*
FROM bands u
inner join statuses s on u.status_id = s.id
WHERE u.status_id = 1
ORDER BY u.band_name";
```

And I would like to output the ID from the `bands` table like so:

```
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
            <tr>
              <?php
                    echo '<td id="' . $row['id'] . '">This is the band</td>';
              ?>
            </tr>
<?php }
```

but `$row['id']` is not outputting anything, I'm guessing due to some sort of ambiguous column issue but I'm not sure how to properly query it. I tried `$row['u.id']` as well but I don't think that is the proper alias use because it didn't output anything either.

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to create non conflicting aliases for the id columns;

```
SELECT u.*, s.*, u.id AS uid, s.id AS sid
FROM bands u
inner join statuses s on u.status_id = s.id
WHERE u.status_id = 1
ORDER BY u.band_name
```

Then you can pick them out as `$row['uid']` and `$row['sid']` and still access your other columns as usual. The conflicting `id` column is also still there, just avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

add an alias on the same column names. ex,

```
SELECT u.id UID,....
```

then you can now retrieve using its alias (*eg. UID*)